# DJANGO: How to render model object name in form instead of literal "model object"?

Tags: django, forms, django-models, many-to-many, inline-formset

I have the following models: Department, Projects, Departmentprojects, Employees, and Membership. A Department has many Projects and Projects have many Employees that are assigned roles through Membership. I am trying to create a InlineFormset so that an EU can assign an Employee's role to multiple projects.

My template renders the right labels and fields, but the Departmentprojects labels and fields don't show the name of the projects. It only shows "Departmentprojects object". How can I get the form to render the name of the project instead of "Departmentprojects object"?

--

Current Template in Browser:

Departmentproject label: (drop down menu with two options listed as "Departmentprojects object")
Role: Project Manager

Desired Template in Browser:

Departmentproject name 1: Project Manager

Departmentproject name 2: Some other role

--

MODELS:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Employees(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Departmentprojects(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Employees, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    departmentprojects = models.ForeignKey(Departmentprojects)
    employees = models.ForeignKey(Employees)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

--

VIEW

```
def addtoprojects(request, employees_id):
    e = get_object_or_404(Employees, pk=employees_id)
    ProjectsInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Employees, Membership, max_num=1)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = ContactInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance=e)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
    else:
        formset = ProjectsInlineFormSet(instance=e)
    return render_to_response('gcstest/contact.html', {'e': e, 'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

--

TEMPLATE

```
<form method="post" action="/assign_to_project/{{ employees.id }}/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I think there's a conceptual error here. What's the point of the `Departmentprojects` model? Are you sure you don't just want to put a foreign-key or many-to-many field linking Projects to Departments, and attach `members` to Projects?

Comment: Also, as a rule, you really want to name your models in the singular, as you did for `Department`. A good reason why is that the line `projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects)` only creates a relationship to a single project, but it reads as if it creates a relationship to many projects.

Comment: sorry new to programming.. but i think i set it up like this because a project can belong to multiple departments. projects table contains only the name of the various projects departments are working on.

Comment: You can allow a Project to be associated with multiple Departments with a `ManyToManyField` (which will add the additional database table for you). The `Departmentprojects` model is really only complicating things, and it's why you're hitting this issue to begin with. For example, cutting out this model will also make it much simpler to get a list of Project members.

Comment: it would make it easier to get a list of project members, but what about a list of project members within a department? wouldn't you not be able to limit the scope of project members to just a department?

Comment: Shouldn't `department` be an attribute of `Employee`? Even if employees have a many-many relationship with Departments, this seems easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) method to your `Departmentprojects` model e.g.

```
class Departmentprojects(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Employees, through='Membership')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s > %s" % (self.department, self.projects)
```

Comment: Why can I not just add "return self.programs"? When I do that I get an errors saying: Caught TypeError while rendering: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Projects found". Also the label still shows Departmentprojects. How can I use just the project name as the label and iterate the form for each project rather than have the drop down menu? (like in the Desired Template in Browser)?